# Zend Framework 2 - How make views separation for frontend and backend?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm a beginner at zf2 and trying to do some sort of folder structuring so make them nice and manageable.

I'm trying to structure my controllers and views in such way that backend related files are in their folder and frontend will be in theirs. I managed to separate my controllers with folders and namespacing them, (ex. Blog\Controller\Frontend\Blog & Blog\Controller\Backend\Blog) and I can make call to them as well using the invokables in the config. However I cannot do that same in the views (Ex. view\blog\frontend\blog & views\blog\backend\blog) as it is looking only in views\blog\blog folder.

Can anyone help how can I fix it so that my views can have some separation of folders for each end?

My module.config.php looks like the following:

```
<?php namespace Blog;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'invokables' => [
            // 'Blog\Controller\Blog' => 'Blog\Controller\BlogController',
            'Blog\Controller\Frontend\Blog' => 'Blog\Controller\Frontend\BlogController',
            'Blog\Controller\Backend\Blog' => 'Blog\Controller\Backend\BlogController',
        ],
    ],

    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'blog' => [
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => '/blog/blog[/:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        // 'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\Blog',
                        'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\Frontend\Blog',
                        'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'         => '[0-9]+',
                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        // 'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\Blog',
                        'controller' => 'Blog\Controller\Frontend\Blog',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],

    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'blog' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ],
    ],

    // Doctrine config
    'doctrine' => [
        'driver' => [
            __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => [
                    __DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity'
                ],
            ],
            'orm_default' => [
                'drivers' => [
                    __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you could've come with `Blog\Controller\BlogFrontend` and `Blog\Controller\BlogBackend` classes. It would've made your life a little bit easier.

If, for one reason or another, you don't want to rename them, you can set a rendering template manually:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate ('application/frontend/blog/index.phtml');
        return $view;
    }
}
```

and in the admin controller

```
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate ('application/backend/blog/index.phtml');
        return $view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked. This is great. Thanks.

I kind of like to see my backend files in one place and frontend files in other that is why I wanted something like this. Your given idea of "BlogFrontend, BlogBackend" is also nice.

Comment: I think this can be a more elegant solution https://github.com/EvanDotPro/EdpModuleLayouts instead of typing on each action  $view->setTemplate ('application/backend/blog/index.phtml');

Comment: The question is not about layouts.